# Install numphy for python on docker.

Tags: bash, python-3.x, powershell, docker

Just started using docker. 
I want to install numphy, scipy etc from bash 
i.e 
*PS H:>* docker run -it python:3.4 bash 
then 
    *....:/#* install requests 
    *....:/#* pip install numphy

I'd expect this to work but for some reason I get the error:

*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numphy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numphy*

Not really sure what to do from here - any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to install `numpy`? You need to use:

```
pip install numpy
```

Not:

```
pip install numphy
```

That package (`numphy`) isn't found because it doesn't exist. You either misspelled it as noted or you don't have the files (if it's a package you'r developing locally) inside the container to install it.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.

Comment: Even trying to use pip install numpy on powershell I get an error message saying pip is not recognised. Even though pip is definitely installed. It's automatically installed with python 3.4 (and onwards) at least. That why I'm trying ton tap into docker.

Comment: What is the “install requests” step? Is that an actual package? Can you try and reproduce again and link to a screenshot of all the steps you’re doing? I replicated that exact error by spelling the package name wrong as noted. I suspect I may have missed a step (I didn’t do anything for requests) and this might be a Python package conflict rather than a Docker issue

Comment: Also pip may be installed locally but is it in your Powershell path? On Mac I use pip3 because that’s how they have it linked (pip2 is Python 2)

Comment: ah it appears I just needed to copy the actual directory instead of 'pip'. Problem solved. Yeah completely new to using windows but thanks for the help anyway